# When user uploads image to AWS S3 from web app hosted on Digital Ocean, is that outbound or inbound bandwidth transfer?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, bandwidth

I’m still new to DO and its services but I’m planning on creating a web app that will allow users to upload images to AWS S3. I intend to host the web app on a DO droplet. Would the image upload be considered inbound or outbound bandwidth transfer? From my understanding, the image is uploaded directly to S3 but since it’s being uploaded from the web app, I would think it’s outbound as it'll have to go through Digital Ocean's servers first (please correct me if I’m wrong).

On a different note, would you recommend performing image resizing/compression on the droplet or offloading that to AWS?

Answer (score 1):

The image upload would be considered an outbound bandwidth transfer. This is because from your droplet you are transferring data using the public network interface to the S3 bucket hosted in AWS, which is an external service.

I am sure you are already aware of the Bandwidth billing details for droplets, in case you aren't here are the details,

> Droplets include free outbound data transfer, starting at 1,000 GiB/month for the smallest plan. Excess data transfer is billed at $0.01/GiB. For example, the cost of 1,000 GiB of overage is $10. Inbound bandwidth to Droplets is always free.
>
> Any data transfer sent by a Droplet using a public network interface will count against the transfer pool for that Droplet's account. All IPv6 traffic uses the public interface. Data transfer between Droplets over a private network or VPC network uses a private network interface.
>
> Transfer allowance is pooled cumulatively at the account level, not individually at the Droplet level. For example, if you run two Droplets for a full month, each with 1,000 GiB/month allowance, you accrue a 2,000 GiB allowance. Let's say you transfer 1,500 GiB of data with the first Droplet, which is over its individual limit, and 100 GiB of data with the second Droplet, you would still be under the total limit of 2000 GiB by 400 GiB and would not be charged any overage fees.

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/accounts/billing/bandwidth/#droplets

To answer your second question,

> Whether to perform image resizing/compression on the droplet or offload it to S3?

AWS S3 is just an object storage service. It does not have the capability to do any processing.
So, your option would be to do the image resizing/compression on the droplet and upload it to S3.

Another option, if you are interested, would be to delegate your image resizing/compression to an AWS Lambda.
In this case, your application hosted in droplet would upload the image to S3. The Lambda gets triggered on image upload, does the image processing and uploads the processed image to S3(you can set and check for a prefix to prevent the Lambda from getting re-triggered).
The advantage of this approach is that your droplet doesn't get loaded on doing CPU-intensive work of image processing, thus enabling it to serve a higher request throughput by simply uploading images and letting the Lambda do the heavy lifting behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. That's exactly what I was thinking about using Lambdas however, the trade-off would be using more outbound bandwidth which DO plans have a limit on. However, if the resizing/compression was done on the droplet, then it'd just consume a bit of RAM or CPU for the moment (not sure how much?) but it wouldn't eat up bandwidth. Now, that's where I'm unsure which trade-off is less expensive or better? I'm not sure how much of the CPU/RAM would be used just for resizing/compression of images

Comment: Another concern is if there's too many uploads and the Lambda linked to the S3 doesn't process the image as fast as I need to serve the image. Then I will be serving an unprocessed image.